# c++ how to put large string into fixed char array

Tags: c++, string, char

Hey I have a very long string and i'm trying to stick it inside of a fixed sized char array. I dont care if the string gets chopped off, i just want each element of the char array to have something.

for example

```
char first_ten_alaphabet[10];
string str = "abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyz";


strcpy(first_ten_alaphabet, str.c_str());  //<-- this will cause program to break
```

any help would be nice thanks

Comment: Perhaps `strncpy(first_ten_alaphabet, 10);`?  Or, better, add `first_ten_alphabet[9] = '\0`;`.

Comment: @FoggyDay `strncpy` is unsafe as it doesn't guarantee the destination is null-terminated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy (and possibly truncate) a C-style string, then I would use [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) instead of "strcpy()".

One limitation of strncpy() is that it will *not* null-terminate the string if the #/characters exactly equals the copy length.  This is by design, but it's a potential "gotcha" if you don't expect it.  Simply add a second statement that puts a NULL character at the final position:

```
char first_ten_alphabet[10];
string str = "abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyz";

strncpy(first_ten_alphabet, str.c_str(), sizeof(first_ten_alphabet));
first_ten_alphabet[sizeof(first_ten_alphabet)-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

use std:copy,http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/ `copy(str.begin(),str.begin()+sizeof(first_ten_alaphabet),first_ten_alaphabet);`